# Mount One drive part of a Raid 1 in another Linux system

Tags: linux, raid1

my system does not have Raid setup and this is my first time that I need to mount a drive that was previously on a Raid system.

I have both drives, and I do need to check the consistency of the files and pull them out, as one of these drives is probably fluffed.

I did follow few threads and I installed mdadm

now if I parted -l I get this, how would I mount it?

> Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label Model: ATA ST31000524AS
>   (scsi) Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
>   Partition Table: unknown Disk Flags:
>
> Error: /dev/md126: unrecognised disk label Model: Linux Software RAID
>   Array (md) Disk /dev/md126: 999GB Sector size (logical/physical):
>   512B/512B Partition Table: unknown Disk Flags:

Comment: have they been part of a soft- or hardware raid?

Comment: 90% possible would have been an HW one set from Bios.

Comment: Hardware raids are usually nearly impossible to recover with simple methods, except you have the same controller

Comment: In simpler words, would I need to plug these 2 drives back where they were, then mount them?

Comment: Thats probably the most promising approach.